# Cython slower compared to Python when using OpenCV

Tags: python, image, numpy, opencv, cython

I am experimenting with Cython and OpenCV and trying to benchmark the performance for image manipulation. I have tried optimizing my Cython code as much as I could, but I still get slower performance with it. I understand most of the code is executed in C because of OpenCV, yet I expected better performance for python loops using Cython. Can anyone tell me if there anything I can do to improve it? Following is my code:

```py
# load_images.py

import cv2
from random import randint
import numpy as np

def fetch_images(n):
    def get_img():
        x = randint(640, 6144)
        y = randint(640, 6144)
        return np.random.rand(x,y, 3).astype(np.uint8)

    return [get_img() for _ in range(n)]

def resize_img(img):
    img = cv2.resize(img, (640, 640))
    return cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)


def preprocess(images):
    return [resize_img(img) for img in images]
```

```py
# load_images_cy.pyx

import cv2
from random import randint
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as np
cimport cython
ctypedef np.uint8_t DTYPE_t

@cython.boundscheck(False)
@cython.wraparound(False)

cdef np.ndarray[DTYPE_t, ndim=3] get_img():
    cdef int x = randint(640, 6144)
    cdef int y = randint(640, 6144)
    return np.random.rand(x,y, 3).astype(np.uint8)

cpdef list fetch_images(int n):
    cdef int _;
    return [get_img() for _ in range(n)]

cdef np.ndarray[DTYPE_t, ndim=2] resize_img(np.ndarray[DTYPE_t, ndim=3] img):
    cdef np.ndarray[DTYPE_t, ndim=3] im;
    im = cv2.resize(img, (640, 640))
    return cv2.cvtColor(im, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)


cpdef np.ndarray[DTYPE_t, ndim=3] preprocess(list images):
    cdef np.ndarray[DTYPE_t, ndim=3] img;
    cdef np.ndarray[DTYPE_t, ndim=3] collection = np.empty((len(images), 640, 640), dtype=np.uint8);
    cdef int i;

    for i, img in enumerate(images):
        collection[i] = resize_img(img)

    return collection
```

```py
# main.py

import load_images_cy
import load_images

import timeit

images = load_images.fetch_images(20)

result_cy = timeit.timeit(lambda: load_images_cy.preprocess(images), number=20)
result_py = timeit.timeit(lambda: load_images.preprocess(images), number=20)
print(f'{result_py/result_cy} times faster')
```

Output:

```
0.9192241989059127 times faster
```

Comment: You've probably not actually used your C-typed variables for anything. So the overall effect of your code is to add a bunch of pointless typechecks (and maybe conversions to/from C-types) but without any of the benefits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cython is primarily meant for interfacing with C code, and writing [Python extension modules](https://docs.python.org/3/extending/extending.html) more easily. While performance improvements can be obtained through Cython, it is not intended to be a drop-in speed-up for Python code.

[PyPy](https://www.pypy.org/), however, is intended to be a more-or-less drop-in speed-up for Python code. It provides an alternate interpreter which is generally faster than CPython, the reference/default Python implementation.

Also, your decorators here:

```
@cython.boundscheck(False)
@cython.wraparound(False)

cdef np.ndarray[DTYPE_t, ndim=3] get_img():
    ...
```

Only apply to `get_img` - not any of the other functions below. Not sure if that was intentional or not. There should not be a blank line between these.

If you want to stick with Cython, and gain performance improvements through it, consider altering [the compilation options](https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/userguide/source_files_and_compilation.html), such as providing `-O2` or `-O3`.

Comment: The decorators pointless anyway - none of the functions really do much indexing. They're copied from somewhere without much thought about whether they'll be useful

Comment: @DavidW Yeah, I wasn't sure why they were there, but I wanted to make it clear that they were only applied to the one function, contrary to what their styling may suggests.

Comment: @DavidW I was actually playing around with every option I came across to see what works. Got it from here: https://blog.paperspace.com/faster-numpy-array-processing-ndarray-cython/

Comment: @LezwonCastellino Yeah, but notice they iterate over an array with tens of thousands up to bilion small entries (numbers) in a tight loop. So there the interpreter overhead is massive and by being able to iterate over the array directly in C, without having to touch the interpreter at all, can they have such significant savings. In your case, the loop has only 20 iterations and all the heavy lifting is done by OpenCV and numpy, so there's negligible potential for gain, and as David mentioned, the extra overhead are probably all the type checks and validations that weren't necessary before.